# How to parse value with rivets.js?

Tags: javascript, django, dashing, rivets.js

I am using [Dashing](https://github.com/talpor/django-dashing) framework based on Django.

HTML using the Rivets.js conventions to bind data to the script file.

```
<div rv-status-color="value">
    <h1>{ title }</h1>
    <h2>{ value }</h2>
    <p class="detail">{ detail }</p>
    <p class="more-info" rv-show="moreInfo">{ moreInfo }</p>
    <p class="updated-at" rv-show="updatedAt">{ updatedAt }</p>
</div>
<i rv-class="icon" rv-show="icon"></i>
```

Following script gets value from HTML and set neccessary color to .css according condition.

```
rivets.binders['status-color'] = function(el, value) {
    if (value == 0) {
        $(el).css('background-color', 'green');
    }
    else if (value < 0) {
        $(el).css('background-color', 'orange');
    }
    else {
        $(el).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
};
```

Could you tell me how to rewrite script to get {detail} value and comparing its with {value}?

Something like that:

```
rivets.binders['status-color'] = function(el, value) {
    if (value == detail) {
        $(el).css('background-color', 'green');
    }
    else if (value < detail) {
        $(el).css('background-color', 'orange');
    }
    else {
        $(el).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
};
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in object to your binder instead of static value.

```
<div rv-status-color="yourObject">
```

And then use the object in script

```
rivets.binders['status-color'] = function(el, obj) {
    if (obj.value == obj.detail) {
        $(el).css('background-color', 'green');
    }
    else if (obj.value < obj.detail) {
        $(el).css('background-color', 'orange');
    }
    else {
        $(el).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank @Bigdragon very much for the fast answer! I've tried but it does not work,meant the widget stopped working at all when I had used  **obj.value** or **obj.detail**.

Comment: Make sure you pass the correct object in `rv-status-color="yourObject"`

Comment: Dear @Bigdragon maybe I did something wrong but it didn't work.

Comment: @Ndew can you try console.log the obj in the binder function? what's it return? or it not going in the binder function at all?

Comment: Dear @Bigdragon Unforunately I cannot upload .log. Could you fix my mistakes here? [link](https://jsfiddle.net/andrew_mug/zxLenf92/) Or show me how it should work?

Comment: @Ndrew Your fiddle doesn't include variables (title, value, etc.) so it should not be working. 
What i mean in the answer is put your parent object (the one that give you `value`, `detail` etc.) in the `rv-status-color=""` attribute and it should enable you to use the data in binder function.

Comment: Dear @Bigdragon I have passed the object. And it works but server stops working in proper way, here part of the log after passing object.[link](https://gist.github.com/abakal/cfe7c0a2ecd697fba94764d3ab4bd320)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do the following:

```
rivets.binders['status-color'] = function(el, value, scope) { //scope being the current bound object
    var detail=scope.detail;
    if (value == detail) {
        $(el).css('background-color', 'green');
    }
    else if (value < detail) {
        $(el).css('background-color', 'orange');
    }
    else {
        $(el).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
};
```